# Calculated Column Formula Syntax Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to setup a list that I can use to calculate deadlines for an approval process. I was asked to set the deadline to 5 working days, and exclude the 2 weekend days. I found a really helpful article, and was attempting to adjust their formula to work with my needs.

However when I made the adjustments, SharePoint threw a syntax error. Here are the formulas:

Original:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=1,WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=7),CurrentDate+3,IF(OR(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=5,WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=6),CurrentDate+4,IF(OR(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)>1,WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)<4),CurrentDate+2)))
```

Adjusted:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=1),CurrentDate+5,IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=7),CurrentDate+6,IF(OR(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)>1,WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)<6,CurrentDate+7))
```

I am assuming I am making a simple mistake (fledgling SP Admin), but could use some expert advice.

Answer (score 1):

Missing parens...

Try this:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=1,CurrentDate+5,IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=7,CurrentDate+6,IF(OR(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)>1,WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)<6),CurrentDate+7)))
```

Here's a shorter version that will probably do what you need:

```
= CurrentDate+5 + IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate+5)=1,1,0) + IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate+5)=7,2,0)
```

(No nested IFs!!!)

Comment: No syntax error, but doesn't handle fridays correctly

Comment: Ah... you asked about the syntax error... I'll add an alternate solution to the above.

Answer (score 0):

You have several small problems:

- Extra close parenthesis after condition in first two IF's
- The last IF has several issues:

  - a close parenthesis for the OR
  - now you have three nested if so you need a close parenthesis more at the end
  - What should happen if WEEKDAY(CurrentDate) = 6?

The best way to play with a formular like this is to use Excel:

1. Create a new notebook
2. Enter a date in A1
3. Label A1 to be CurrendDate
4. Now you can play with the formular in A2 (or any other cell)

My suggestion:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=1,CurrentDate+5,IF(WEEKDAY(CurrentDate)=7,CurrentDate+6,CurrentDate+7))`

or if you can assume that items are only created on working days

`=CurrentDate+7`

Comment: =CurrentDate+7 
... sometimes it is the simple answers. Have a ways to go gents, thanks for the help.